# Error visualizando página desde apache: se ve el código fuente

Tags: apache

Cuando acceso a mi página, no la veo; solo veo el código fuente.

En vez de ver:

## AAAAAAAAAAAAAA

veo el html y el resto del código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
</head>
<body>  
<h1>AAAAAAAAAAAAAA</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Uso la versión 2.4 de Apache

Comment: Hola Ricardo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español (completa el [tour] para aprender sobre el sitio y su funcionamiento general, y co ello ganar una medalla). Y enhorabuena por tu primera pregunta, es interesante y se ajusta bien al formato del sitio. Queda atento por si algún usuario pregunta algo, para poder resolver cualquier duda y que sea más fácil ayudarte. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Qué extensión tiene tu fichero?

Comment: Hola. El fichero es Index.html y si lo abro pulsado dos veces se ve correcto. Pero desde el navegador (de escritorio o el movil) sale eso.

Comment: ¿En qué servidor GNU/Linux o MS Windows? porque si es Windows, hay que tener en cuenta que esconde algunas extensiones por defecto, asegura que es .html y no .html.txt o similar.

Comment: Es windows y la extensión es html. No se si habré tocado algo en el httpd.conf. Hace unas semanas funcionaba y al volver a probarlo hoy ya no iba

Comment: Prueba a comentar las líneas de MIMEMagicFile en httpd.conf (como se sugiere en [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37714730/3695983))

Comment: Ya funciona. No he tocado nada, simplemente ha vuelto a funcionar. Ahora el problema está en que no lee el fichero css. En el head añado esta linea < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="res/app.css"/ > y en la carpeta res esta el fichero. Si lo abro con la dirección ip no se aplican los estilos pero si lo abro directamente si...

Comment: Esto parece un problema de configuración con Apache, vas a tener que añadir algo más de información a la pregunta (p.e. los ficheros de configuración o los logs del servidor) para que sea más fácil concretar el problema y ayudarte.

Comment: No puedo dejarlo aquí, me faltan caracteres. Que parte de la configuración puede estar relacionada, para escribir solo eso?

Comment: Parece ser un error de que no esté corriendo el apache, asegúrate de que esté funcionando y si las rutas de los estilos no te funciona, prueba con ponerle al principio el `./`, quedando `href="./res/app.css"`

Comment: Tampoco funciona. Apache me sirve la página pero sin cargar el css. He probado con ./res/app.css y con app.css copiando el fichero en la misma carpeta de index.html y nada. He instalado nginx y funciona bien pero tiene que ser apache